# SQLObject install without internet

Tags: python, linux, python-2.6, sqlobject

Trying to setup a python flask server in a controlled environment, no access to internet

```
# python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    use_setuptools()
  File "/tmp/app_dependencies/SQLObject-3.1.0/ez_setup.py", line 150, in use_setuptools
    version = _resolve_version(version)
  File "/tmp/app_dependencies/SQLObject-3.1.0/ez_setup.py", line 358, in _resolve_version
    resp = urlopen(meta_url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1198, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 1165, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to install from a wheel file

```
pip install SQLObject-version.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing from sources without an Internet connection you have to have dependencies — FormEncode, PyDispatcher and backend drivers — installed before installing SQLObject.

Comment: thanks phd, i was able to get those deps, but the question was to install sqlobject itself.

Comment: Oh, I see, the computer doesn't even have an IP stack! use_setuptools() [was removed](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/commit/dec28cb8e3a3aab0f819b7f2d8d45190d8cab2a4#diff-2eeaed663bd0d25b7e608891384b7298L9) at January; the fix was included in SQLObject 3.2.0 and later.